# javascript allow redirection only for urls inside same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect

I have a javascript which handles a "redirect after login" concern by setting

```
window.location = url;
```

where "url" is provided by a GET parameter. 
This sounds a bad practice because it allows to redirect outside of current domain.

So I would like to know how if there is an easy and safe way to **check if "url" is an absolute url inside same domain and allow redirection only in this case**. 
Currently I just check if url starts with "/" and doesn't contain "http" but I'm not sure it's enough to completely protect against open redirections.

```
if (url[0] === '/' && url.indexOf('http') === -1)
{
    window.location = url;
}
```

As I do this on client side I'm aware it's still not perfect but previously there were no protection at all.

I can use good old JS or jquery. I also have to support IE9.

late edit : maybe I didn't mentioned it clearly enough but the "url" should be an absolute url, without domain specification. 
For example I have this kind of address (full address with url parameter at end) :
http://example.com/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fCheckout.aspx

I need to avoid : 
http://example.com/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://otherdomain/badintention.aspx

This is why I told above I currently check if it starts by "/" but I'm not sure it's enough to get safe. So I can't use some of your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the (rather new) [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) Api:

```
var redirUrl = "http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path";
var currentHost = location.host;

if (new URL(redirUrl).host != currentHost)
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Unfortunately I have to support IE9 and other quite old browsers. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just issue an HTTP 307 temporary redirect from the server and not have to worry about client code? It seems more secure that way.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Otherwise, your javascript could also check against window.location.hostname.

EDIT: if you're only going to allow relative URLs, it seems like checking for '/' at the beginning should be fairly safe as long as you're 100% sure it's a URL, but you can probably even add the window.location.hostname to the beginning to be absolutely sure you're squashing the possibility of semantic trickery.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough but the supplied url should not contain domain at all, only absolute url with "/" at the beginning.

Comment: You mean relative URL? I'm tweaking my answer to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

you can fetch the current domain name with window.document.domain and check if the url provided by GET operation has this?

Sorry it should ideally be a comment but do not have enough privileges.

Comment: anything that should be a comment should not be an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough but the supplied url should not contain domain at all, only absolute url with "/" at the beginning.